# haskell -- how to create a binary from a non-Main module?

Tags: haskell, compilation, ghc

I often have situations where I leave `main :: IO ()` functions in tests. I can run these fine with `runghc`, but sometimes I want to compile them (e.g. for running on another platform). Is there a way to do this? If I run, for example,

```
ghc --make Test.Haar
```

where `Test/Haar.hs`  has a `main` method, then nothing happens, it just creates the `.o` file.

Comment: I am not sure if that is what you are looking for, but check out -main-is option (docs at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/options-phases.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ghc --make -main-is Test.Haar Test.Haar
```

Answer (score 4):

Note, however, that after using `-main-is Test.Haar`, if you want to use the module as part of another programme, you have to recompile it without the `-main-is`, otherwise the linker will find two entry-points and throw an error.